# fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Private repo

Tags: git, github

I have access to private repository. I can see it in my github. After that I use 
git clone and I make some changes on my local machine.

Now I try to make git push on this repo and I can see:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I saw .git/config and all urls are good.

How to solve this problem?

**SOLVED**

Firstly I needed to create Fork of private project. Next Clone project to local machine and then add

```
git remote add uppstream githubURL
```

Next commit, add files and push. After that pull request.

Comment: How are you authenticated?

Comment: I get email to join this repository. After that I made changes and owner of this repository told me to create  pull request to this repo.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to solve this problem?

SOLVED

Firstly I needed to create Fork of private project. Next Clone project to local machine and then add

```
git remote add uppstream githubURL
```

Next commit, add files and push. After that pull request.

Answer (score 1):

First: you need to check the remote server of your local repository.

You can get a list of any configured remote urls with the command

> git remote -v

Second: if the remoter server is OK, you need to check whether you have permission to push to GitHub, there are two ways to access the GitHub server, one is using email and password, the other is using SSH which is more convenient. [GitHub ssh keey](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)